# How to undo pressing Don't Trust on Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I want to test out my watch app on Xcode. So I plugged my iPhone paired with an Apple Watch Series 2 into my computer. The iPhone displayed a dialog saying whether to trust this computer or not, I clicked on trust and the iPhone is properly displayed in Xcode. In a minute the same popup appeared on my Watch, however I accidentally clicked Don't Trust on the Apple Watch, now the watch doesn't show up in Xcode. Usually to fix this for iPhone I would just plug the phone into the computer again, but I tried that, and the popup did not reappear on my Watch.

Is there a way to trust my computer again without erasing all datas on the Watch?

Comment: how do you plug an apple watch into a computer?

Comment: @dwightk you don't, that connection just happens and of course is definitely not documented on Apple support documents.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same message on my Apple Watch and responded "Don't Trust" since I had no idea what computer was trying to connect. Then I read [this article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7247577?answerId=32509459022#32509459022) so opened the Console app on my Mac. Initially it didn't show my Apple Watch under Devices. I think I had to connect my iPhone to my computer first before both my iPhone and Apple Watch showed up, the latter with an exclamation icon due to the "Don't Trust" response.

I disconnected my iPhone from my computer and restarted the iPhone. I then reconnected it to my computer to check the status in Console again. I got the "Trust this computer" prompt on my Apple Watch again. After responding "Trust" this time and entering my PIN, the warning icon disappeared in Console after a few moments.

It should be noted that there may be delays before the Apple Watch shows up in Console. I think opening Xcode seems to hasten the discovery process but I'm not sure. Also, I have yet to see any Apple Watch log entries in Console.

Comment: For me it was enough restarting the Apple Watch. I had Xcode running as well.

Comment: In my case, I spent all afternoon trying to get a Trust This Computer message to be displayed again. I found the only solution was to unpair my watch from my phone then pair it again as a new watch. This is not nice because it meant I had to reinput all my settings on my watch. Having re-paired, I started Xcode and then got a Trust this Computer message on my watch. All good, I pressed OK (or whatever the button said) then entered my PIN. The first time, I hit the cancel button below the PIN keypad (sausage fingers) and had to unpair and pair again.

Comment: Secondly, to get the console app to display watch logs, you need to copy the sysdiagnose profile (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/) to your iPhone and then install it - it will install itself on your watch. I saved this profile in my iCloud Documents folder so I could easily get at it from my phone

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is documented nowhere on Apple support documents so I wish you good luck in figuring this out.

There is an open Apple Community Forum discussion on this topic which you might want to contribute to and/or vote as of interest (https://discussions.apple.com/message/33472303) but given how rarely Apple employees actually contribute to these forums with official answers I would not hold my breath until an acceptable answer is posted for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Shutdown Xcode.
2. Disconnect iPhone from laptop
3. Power down iPhone.
4. Power down Apple Watch (press and hold crown and side button for about 10s)
5. Restart iPhone
6. Restart Apple Watch (press and release crown, Apple logo should appear)
7. Start up Xcode.  Don't open your project just yet.
8. Attach phone to laptop
9. Xcode -> Windows -> Devices & Simulators
10. There should be a banner across the top of the D&S window indicating that the phone and/or phone and watch is/are getting ready for development.  Wait for that to complete.
11. When complete, open your project and run on the watch.

Answer (score -3):

For an iPhone, you'd go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy to have it forget all the computers it trusts and distrusts. Try this:

1. Press Home on iPhone to display the Home screen.
2. Tap Apple Watch to open the Apple Watch app.
3. Tap My Watch and the My Watch screen will appear.
4. Tap Privacy to display the Privacy Settings screen.
5. Look for an option to Reset Location & Privacy.

I don't have an Apple Watch to verify this, but I hope it helps

Comment: There is no such setting on the Apple Watch nor on the iPhone Watch app.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't have a watch to check it with. Thanks for checking that out for me